# Is it a good practise to inject properties into ReactJS functional components using literal dot notation setters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object, properties

Fiddling with a React code written by someone else, I stumbled upon this pattern:

```
// So far so good:
const displayName = 'aComponentsName'
const propTypes = {
  // not important
}

const aFunctionalComponent = () => 'someJSX, not important'

// That's what baffles me:
aFunctionalComponent.displayName = displayName
aFunctionalComponent.propTypes = propTypes
```

I know that technically, functions are objects and thay can have properties, even methods:

```js
const func = () => 'somevalue'

func.foo = 'foo'
func.bar = 'bar'
func.baz = () => 'hello world'

console.dir(func) // Sadly, can't be expanded in SO sandbox, but the props are there
console.log(func.foo, func.bar)
console.log(func.baz())
```

**My question is**: Is it O.K.? Do you use it? Is it a neat way to inject a bunch of (rather static) state-like properties into a stateless component, or is it a hack which I should avoid?

Comment: It depends on what `foo` and `bar` are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`displayName` and `propTypes` are specific properties, that's why they were set in the example.

[`displayName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/displayName) is non-standardized property that contains function name. As opposed to `name`, it can be set manually and contain readable name even when a function is minified. It can be used for debugging (by React devtools in particular) or as a common way to provide original function name, e.g.:

```
function callFn(fn) {
  console.log('Calling function: ',  fn.displayName || fn.name);
  return fn();
}

callFn(aFunctionalComponent);
```

`propTypes` is used by [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) to do type checks at runtime.

Whether it's a good or bad practice to provide data as function properties depends on particular case.

Comment: Thank you. So may I conclude that in case of `displayName` and `propTypes`, it is O.K. to use this 'injection'?

Comment: I wouldn't call it injection. These properties provide additional data about function. It's ok in these specific cases.